# Custom domain for Bluemix IoT

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud, iot

We are starting our Bluemix IoT infrasctructure with IoTF and I am wondering about DNS issues in my devices.
When I ship my IoT devices with a pre-configured organization ID, which is generated by Bluemix like `orgid.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com`, how can I customize this address to `mqtt.myorganization.com` to have the ability to create other IoT instances without re-configuring my device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am interpreting your question 100% correctly but you do have the option to customize your route in Bluemix.  When you view your app in the dashboard and click on the  pencil icon near the route link, a popup appears which allows you to edit the route for your application. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you did create other organizations, and wanted your devices to connect using credentials from that org, you would need to supply those credentials to the devices.  This data includes the orgid so its not clear what problem you are trying to address.

The  in .messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com and .internetofthings.ibmcloud.com URLs serves 2 purposes:

1. Acts as a CNAME for your organization's datacenter messaging URL.  For example if your organization is in us-south then that URL is an alias for us.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com.  If your organization is in eu-gb, then that URL is an alias for uk.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com.  So you could use those URLs as appropriate, or you could have your own DNS entry resolve to the IP addresses that they resolve to.
2. In the V2 API the .internetofthings.ibmcloud.com is crucial in routing your request appropriately.  If you do not use that format you cannot use the V2 API because there is no path parameter for orgid any more.

Hope that helps.

Paul